# Showing an array as undefined after concatanating it in Promise in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I have a function :

```
filterAllComponent(inputdata) {
    let a=[], b=[],c=[];
    a=  this.getfilterPlaces(inputdata);
    b= this.getfilterTransporter(inputdata);
    c= this.getfilterVehicles(inputdata);

    let getplaceArray = [],
  getTransporterArray = [],
  getVehicleArray = [];

let getPlacePromise = function () {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getplaceArray = a;
    resolve("got places\n");
  });
};

let getTransporterPromise = function (message) {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getTransporterArray =  b
    resolve(message + "got Transporter");
  });
};

let getVehiclePromise = function (message) {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getVehicleArray = c
    resolve(message + "got vehicle");
  });
};

getPlacePromise().then(function (result) {
  return getTransporterPromise(result);
}).then(function (result) {
  return getVehiclePromise(result);
}).then(function (result) {
  var AllDropdownValues = getTransporterArray.concat(getVehicleArray).concat(getplaceArray);
  console.log(AllDropdownValues);
});


}
```

Need to concatanate the array AllDropdownValues with **getVehicleArray**, **getplaceArray** and **getTransporterArray**. 
In the final result the array **getplaceArray** is showing undefined. Rest of the result are showing correctly.

The calling functions :

```
getfilterTransporter(autocompleteInputData) {

    var k= this.checkRegex(autocompleteInputData);
    this.getfilteredTransporter= this.filterTransporters(k);
    return this.formatTransporterValue(this.getfilteredTransporter);
}
getfilterVehicles(autocompleteInputData) {

  var k= this.checkRegex(autocompleteInputData);
    this.getfilteredVehicle= this.filterVehicles(k);
    return this.formatVehicleValue(this.getfilteredVehicle);
}
getfilterPlaces(autocompleteInputData) {
  if (autocompleteInputData == '' || typeof(autocompleteInputData) == 'object') 
  return null;
  this.placeData.getPlacesFromPig(autocompleteInputData)
  .subscribe(response =>
    return this.formatPigResponse(response);
   }); 

}
```

for **getfilterPlaces**, subscribe() is used to extract data from the API call. but when I call the function filterAllComponent(), getfilterPLaces is not populated but other two functions are doing Ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is, that the `return expression` within your subscription isn't given back as the `return value` of the `getfilterPlaces function`. This means, that your `getfilterPlaces function` has no specified `return value`, if `autocompleteInputData` is set and no object.

The problem is, that `this.placeData.getPlacesFromPig` seems to be an asynchronous function and returning an `rjxs Observable` or something similar. One way to avoid this problem is using the `await` operator and the [`async function` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). To do so, you have to mark your `getfilterPlaces` and `filterAllComponent functions` as `async` and use `a = await this.getfilterPlaces(inputData)`. Also, `getfilterPlaces` needs to return a `Promise`. Assuming that `this.placeData.getPlacesFromPig` returns an `rxjs Observable`, the code would look like this:

```
async function getfilterPlaces(autocompleteInputData) {
  if (autocompleteInputData == '' || typeof(autocompleteInputData) == 'object') 
    return null;
  return this.placeData.getPlacesFromPig(autocompleteInputData)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => this.formatPigResponse(response));
}
```

---

```
async function filterAllComponent(inputdata) {
  let a=[], b=[], c=[];
  a = await this.getfilterPlaces(inputdata);
  b = this.getfilterTransporter(inputdata);
  c = this.getfilterVehicles(inputdata);
[...]
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. This exactly what i needed. Worked perfectly